# Making SSL connections without intermediate certificates using HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to connect to a site using SSL where the client only has the root certificate, but the server has both the root and the intermediate certificates?

I am trying to connect using HttpUrlConnection with a TrustManager containing my roots, and I get the usual handshake error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
  Certificate chaining error
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
```

I know that the general solution is to install the intermediate certificates, but I would like to avoid the constant one-offing of getting vendor X's new intermediate certificate.

I am familiar with using a TrustManager that accepts everything, but that is not an option.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When a server has a certificate signed by a sub-ca-A which is signed by a root CA (e.g. Verisign), then the server will send all the certificates as part of the server hello so that the server's certificate can be validated.

In your case you only have the root CA in the truststore.

As a result it is impossible to get up the validation chain of trust since you are missing the sub-ca certificate.
It is not only impossible, it would be wrong/insecure to be able to do that. So what you are doing is way out of proper path.

So you only have 2 options.
Put the **server's actual certificate** in the truststore as trusted.
Put the **whole chain** in the truststore i.e. the intermediate CA certificates along with the root.

What are your concerns? Intermediate certificate expiration?

Comment: My concern is the constant one off additions that would need to be made to add intermediate certificates.  Occasionally, a customer would have a script that would make a call out to an external server, and the result wold be the SSL handshake error.  We would then have to drop everything we are doing to add that new intermediate certificate.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, your setup has a Root CA and e.g. X delegate sub-CAs. And so you want to avoid storing in the truststore the sub-CA certificates and only keep the 1 certificate of the root CA.There is only 1 way to do this that I can think of, and that is even harder to get right and depends on many things.If your certificate of the servers include an address where the issuer of the certificate can be be downloaded, it could be possible to get it dynamically and build the chain on the spot.But to be honest I am not sure if it is easy to be done right

Comment: Yes, I had thought of connecting using a "no trust" keystore in order to acquire the certificates, and check if they use one of our roots, and build the chain using the getCertificates call.  There is also a trust issue with the intermediate certificates.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. The server will send all the certificates including the intermediate cert and the root. The client has the root. The client can therefore validate the entire chain, and find a trusted anchor. So what the OP describes should work.

Comment: @EJP: Yes, this answer does not make sense. Probably some kind of misunderstanding. Your answer is correct :-).

Comment: This answer is wrong. If the root CA cert is trusted by the client, that is all that should be needed to establish the chain of trust. People version: I trust Jim and Jim trusts Shankar, so therefor I can trust Shankar.

Answer (score 18):

> Is it possible to connect to a site using SSL where the client only
> has the root certificate, but the server has both the root and the
> intermediate certificates?

This is not only possible, but actually the usual way that TLS works:

1. The TLS client only has the root certificates. Java - at least the Oracle JVM - reads them from `lib/security/cacerts` in the JRE installation directory. Browsers either have their own, internal list, or use a list provided by the operating system.
2. When a client initiates a TLS connection, the server is supposed to send back its own certificate, along with any intermediate certificates (if it uses any) - this list is called the *certificate chain*. For the current version 1.2. of TLS this is specified in [section 7.4.2 of RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2) (see below for quote).
3. The client receives these certificate(s), and verifies the signatures, from the server certificate up to one of the root certificates it knows. This is referred to as *Certification Path Building*, and is described in [RFC 4158](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4158).
4. If the client can build a valid certification path, it continues with connection setup. Otherwise, it aborts with an error message - something like the dreaded "This connection is untrusted" error.

> I know that the general solution is to install the intermediate
> certificates

No, actually not, as explained above the server *should* automatically send all intermediate certificates.

**However:**

One fairly common configuration error on servers is to not install all intermediate certificates on the server. In that case the server will send an incomplete certificate chain during connection setup. Then the client will not be able to build a valid certification path, and will abort the connection.

Some complications can make this problem hard to diagnose:

- Some clients (particularly browsers) may still connect successfully, because they have a cached copy of the missing intermediate certificate.
- Most clients do not or cannot distinguish between a missing intermediate certificate (in the chain sent by the server), a missing root certificate (in their own list), and a self-signed certificate, so you'll have to figure out yourself what the problem actually is.

Useful tools for diagnosing these problems:

- OpenSSL's command line client can show you the certificate chain a server sends: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443`
- Qualys' [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) will list the certificate chain, along with any verification errors

---

Relevant quote from [section 7.4.2 of RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2):

> 7.4.2.  Server Certificate
>
> When this message will be sent:
>
> The server MUST send a Certificate message whenever the agreed- upon
> key exchange method uses certificates for authentication (this
> includes all key exchange methods defined in this document except
> DH_anon).  This message will always immediately follow the ServerHello
> message.
>
> Meaning of this message:
>
> This message conveys the server's certificate chain to the client.
>
> [...]
>
> Structure of this message:
>
> [...]
>
> certificate_list
>
> This is a sequence (chain) of certificates.  The sender's certificate
> MUST come first in the list.  Each following certificate MUST directly
> certify the one preceding it.  Because certificate validation requires
> that root keys be distributed independently, the self-signed
> certificate that specifies the root certificate authority MAY be
> omitted from the chain, under the assumption that the remote end must
> already possess it in order to validate it in any case.

Comment: Yup. This. Right. Here.

Answer (score 7):

The server should send the *entire* certificate chain, including the intermediate certificate, in the `Certificate` message. The client will check the entire chain and find the root certificate that it trusts. So what you are describing should work.

Of course, it is possible to (mis)configure a server not to send the entire chain - in that case the check by the client may fail.

Comment: I agree, logically it should work. The entire chain is verifiable by the client, and it just needs to check that a trusted Root signed the last guy in the received chain. If we are missing something here, I'd like to learn what. The only thing is to make sure to configure the server to send the full chain instead of just its own cert. Disagree with the accepted answer.

Comment: @AmitNaidu: Exactly. The problem is that some servers are (mis)configured and do not send the complete chain. I tried to explain this in my answer. I took the liberty of editing that into the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/162592/why-do-i-need-to-add-intermediate-ca-certificates-to-jvms-cacerts-file#answer-168061):

Using the Oracle JRE you can enable automatic downloading of intermediate certificates with the Java system property `-Dcom.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers=true`

For this to work the server's certificate must provide the URI to the intermediate certificate (the certificate's issuer).